# What are the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Consider a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ in the form:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 
       \alpha & \beta  &  0     & \cdots & 0                 \\
       \gamma & \alpha & \beta  & \cdots & 0                 \\
        0     & \gamma & \alpha & \cdots & \vdots            \\
       \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \beta             \\
        0     &  0     & \cdots & \gamma & \operatorname{\alpha}
       \end{bmatrix} $$

Then a closed form expression for the eigenvalues is

$$\mu_k = \alpha + 2 \beta \sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{\beta}} \cos \left( \frac{k \pi}{n+1} \right)$$

However, this also requires that $\beta \neq 0$, since the corresponding eigenvectors contain a division by $\beta$. Therefore, I am wondering if there exists a separate general formula for the case where $\beta = 0$.

This simplifies the above matrix $M$ to:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
\alpha & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   \gamma & \alpha & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
   0 & \gamma & \alpha & \cdots & \vdots \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & \cdots & \gamma & \operatorname{\alpha}
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Of course, it is simple enough to compute this manually for smaller matrices, but I would be interested in knowing what the general solution is in this case.

---

*Note: the corresponding eigenvectors in the case where $\beta \neq 0$ are:* $$v_k = \Big{(} \sqrt{ \frac{\gamma}{\beta}} \sin \big{(} \frac{ k \pi}{n+1} \big{)}, \big{(} \sqrt{ \frac{\gamma}{\beta}} \space \big{)}^2 \sin \big{(} \frac{ 2k \pi}{n+1} \big{)}, \cdots, \big{(} \sqrt{\frac{\gamma}{\beta}} \space \big{)}^n \sin \big{(} \frac{ nk \pi}{n+1} \big{)} \Big{)}^T$$

Comment: [Tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices: properties and novel applications](https://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf) (2006)

Comment: Can't you eliminate the divide by zero by simplifying?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The matrix you've written is lower triangular, and the eigenvalues of triangular matrices are just their diagonal entries.  In particular, your matrix has only one eigenvalue, $\alpha$, and it occurs with algebraic multiplicity $n$.

Answer (score 8):

One can also note that you can take the limit as $\beta$ goes to zero in your expression, since while it does include a division by $\beta$, that is also multiplied by the same to a higher power; that is, you can simplify the expression for the eigenvalues to
$$
\mu_k = \alpha + 2\sqrt{\beta\gamma}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)
$$